# error: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I'm trying to implement a login function that allows me to extract data from facebook and save them on my moodle Website. Unfortunately, I'm not a programmer and I'm having some problems. In particular, I'm having some difficulties -I believe- related to the permission rights when I try to "write" the data extracted from fb on a MySQL database.

This is what I have done so far:

I managed to extract from Fb the data that interest me and I tried to save them to a MySQL database (created through cpannel). The code I used to access the database is basically this (with the correct parameters for my database):

```
// Create connection

$ Db = new mysqli ($ localhost, $ username, $ password, $ database);

// Check connection

if ($ db> connect_error) {

    die ( "Connection failed:". $ db-> connect_error);

}
```

But when I connect to the web page I get this error: "Connection failed: Access denied for user 'root' @ 'localhost' (using password: NO)"

The problem seems to be that the user/pass are incorrect. In fact, I am sure the data correspond to those included in CPannel by me at the time of database creation. The associated user has all active privileges.

I did some research and it it seemed that the problem could be associated with some "automatic" setting of Moodle. So I uninstalled moodle but nothing has changed.

I also tried to change the code:

```
$config = parse_ini_file('/config.ini');

// Connect to database

$mysqli = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], $config['password'], $config['dbname']);

printf("\n ".date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") . " - Establishing connection to " . $config['dbname'] . " on " . $config['servername'] . ".\n");

// Check connection

if ($mysqli->connect_error) {

    die('Error : (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') ' . $mysqli->connect_error);

    printf("\n ".date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") . " - Connection failed. Returned error: " . mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");

} else {

     printf("\n ".date("Y-m-d h:i:sa") . " - Connection successful.\n");

}
```

Unfortunately I had no luck ...

This is the tutorial i followed to implement the function:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5Kka43giyY&index=30&list=PLmpuiTmSb3xCLwwkpXeuJxwKyljf7e3Tx

I am very inexperienced, but it seems to me that the problem arises when I define password in cpannel ... it is as if the password had no value ..
Any ideas on how I can resolve it?

Comment: Try removing the spaces between the `$` and the `variable` name. Then it might become valid PHP

Comment: Kinda looks lik e you have no value set in `$ password` or `$config['password']`

Comment: @RiggsFolly I agree with you. The problem is that I define a password when I create the new user associated with the database!!It seems that this password has no value..

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be related to the host parameter of the connection, review your CPanel data and try to find the host, like an IP address or domain provided by your CPanel.

Comment: Thank you wolmi. I tried that but with no luck..maybe i have an idea: I installed moodle on the site with softalculous. This process has automatically created a database and a new user that seem work well. If I can see which is the password for this user, I could associate him to my new database and perhaps it will work ..Does anyone know where I can find this information? I have already tried to change the password for this user, but it worked against me. Big problems with database so that I had to repeat the installation ..

Answer (score -1):

You can replace $config['password'] with real password like 'your-password' in your below mysql query

$mysqli = new mysqli($config['servername'], $config['username'], 'your-password', $config['dbname']);